# Copy G Suite drive files and folders from one domain to another domain

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm trying to query list of all files and folders from drive of G Suite user and copy all this files to another domain user.

Anyhow i am able to get list of all files but i am not able copy those files to another domain.
I have gone through several reference on sharing drive files but couldn't understand of granting authority so that destination domain can copy files.

I will be happy if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

```
public void Execute(){

    string strFileId = "";
    //get list of all files from source domain(eg. user@a.jp)
    IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> fileList = service.getDriveFiles();

    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File title = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
    //loop files list
    foreach (var fileItem in fileList)
    {
       strFileId = fileItem.Id;
       title.Name = fileItem.Name;
      //copy files to destination domain(eg. user@b.jp) with file ID
       service.Files.Copy(title, strFileId).Execute();
    }
}


private IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> getDriveFiles()
{
   // Define parameters of request.
   Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest FileListRequest = source_drive_service.Files.List();
   // get all files
   FileListRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(*)";

   IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = FileListRequest.Execute().Files;
   return files;
}
```

Comment: You want to copy the files from one Drive to another Drive in a different domain ?

Comment: yes, I am trying to copy the files from one Drive to another Drive in a different domain using c#.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this, but one simple way is to:

1. With the Drive API get a list of all your files (which include folders in Drive) by using the [`Files.list()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).
2. For every file, you can [transfer  ownership](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing#transfer_file_ownership) to a new owner (the admin of Domain B for example).

**Note:** *When a file is transferred, the previous owner's role is downgraded to writer.*

Comment: Thank you for answering. I’ll be grateful if you can give some ideas or way to share the root folder of the Drive in domain A, with an account in domain B.

Comment: Sorry if what I meant was misleading. There is no way of changing the permissions of the  'Root' folder because it can not be retrieved as a folder, it is essentially the whole drive itself. So the simple alternative is to transfer ownership of everything in the Drive as I updated in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I did with transferring ownership to a new owner like you mentioned [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing#transfer_file_ownership).
Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad I helped. Please have a look at [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).